# having issue with attaching the PDF file from memory stream using ITextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, memorystream

I am having problem with attaching the PDF file created in-memory and attaching it to email template.

email goes without any problem..BUT there is no attachment. I don't understand why this is happening.

here is the complete code for the process.

```
ExtendedEmailTemplate emailTemp = new ExtendedEmailTemplate();
emailTemp.FromAddress = "ABC Ltd <info@abcTechnology.com>";
emailTemp.ToAddress = custEmail;
emailTemp.Body = "This is an Test Email"
emailTemp.IsHTML = true;

// getting the memorystream of cretaed PDF file in memory
MemoryStream pdfStream = MWProductGuaranteedHelper.CreateProductGuaranteeCertificatePDF(custName, guranteeCode, productName);

// getting the MailMessage by passing the memorystream and attach the PDF
MailMessage emailMessage = ExtendedEmailTemplate.GenerateMailMessage(emailTemp, pdfStream);

// sending an email with by passing the (MailMessage)
emailTemp.SendGuaranteeCertificateAttachmentEmail(emailMessage);
```

---

### Create PDF in memory

```
public static MemoryStream CreateProductGuaranteeCertificatePDF(string custName, string guaranteeCode, string productName)
  {
      MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
      string guaranteedUntil = DateTime.Now.AddYears(3).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

      string fromFile = Server.MapPath(guaranteeCertificateFilePath);
       PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fromFile);
       PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memoryStream);
       AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

       // AcroFields setting CODE EMITTED 

      stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;  // making sure that stream stays open after closing the stamper
      stamper.FormFlattening = false;
      stamper.Close();
      reader.Close();

      memoryStream.Position = 0;  // reset the position of the stream, so that attachment works right
      return memoryStream;
  }
```

---

### Generate MailMessage

```
public static MailMessage GenerateMailMessage(ExtendedEmailTemplate template, MemoryStream _ms)
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(template.FromAddress);
        mailMessage.To.Add(template.ToAddress);
        mailMessage.Subject = template.Subject;
        mailMessage.Body = template.Body;
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(_ms, "ABC-Certificate.Pdf", "application/pdf"));
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = template.IsHTML;

        return mailMessage;
    }
```

---

### Sends an Email

```
public void SendGuaranteeCertificateAttachmentEmail(MailMessage _message)
    {
        EmailClient.Send(_message);
    }

 public static void Send(MailMessage mailMessage) // SMTP Settings CODE Emitted. 
        {
                //SEND THE MAIL MESSAGE
                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
```

I don't know what going wrong with this code...email goes without any attachment.

help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see what you are doing wrong but I am doing something similar, although create my pdf by parsing a web page.
Here's what I do:

```
  public static Attachment GetPDfAttachmentFromUrl(string url)
        {
            string download = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80, 50, 30, 65);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
            try
            {
                StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(download);
                List<IElement> parsedList = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(stringReader, null);
                document.Open();
                foreach (object item in parsedList)
                {
                    document.Add((IElement)item);
                }
                document.Close();
                stringReader.Close();

                MemoryStream pdfstream = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
//create attachment
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(pdfstream, "transaction.pdf");

                return attachment;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Then in a separate place I send it like so:

```
  MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, to);
        mm.Body = body;
        mm.Subject = subject;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mm.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Send(mm);
```

Does this help at all?

Comment: This certainly helps if i am using the PDFWriter. in my case i am using PDFStamper..

Comment: The main difference I can see is I am doing this:   MemoryStream pdfstream = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray()); and then using that memory stream. Maybe try that? Rather than the one you are passing to the stamper?

Comment: `MemoryStream pdfstream = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());` was the key. It would be nice to understand why that works, and the other doesn't...