# View PDF in Browser in new window on button click and delete file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having issue with deleting file created just to send an email with attachment and then view it in browser. now i need to delete this file as this is created to just send email. how can i do this.

here is what i have got so far.

```
public void SendEmail()
 {
    EmailClient.Send(mailMessage);

    //View PDF Certificate in Browser
    ViewPDFinBrowser((string)fileObject);

    DeleteGeneratedTempCertificateFile((string)fileObject));
}    

public void ViewPDFinBrowser(string filePath)
  {
     PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

     PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
     stamper.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.PageLayoutSinglePage | PdfWriter.PageModeUseThumbs;
     stamper.Close();

     Response.Clear();
     Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
     Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
     Response.OutputStream.Close();
     HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

  }

  public static void DeleteGeneratedTempCertificateFile(Object fileObject)
  {
      string filePath = (string)fileObject;
      if (File.Exists(filePath))
      {
          File.Delete(filePath);
      }
  }
```

So here are the steps i need when i call SendEmail()

1) Sends an email with the attachment --> Temp file created 
2) view the temp file in the browser
3) delete the temp file

I can understand that as long as file is in response object, i can not do anything with it because i get the error message ("File used by another process). If i close the response stream then file will be deleted but then i cant view it in browser.

i was thinking if i can manage to somehow open the file to view in browser in new window on button click, i will be able to delete the file.
OR
i am thinking i can delete the file after 10 min. as user wont be on site viewing the PDF for more then 1-2 mins.

please advice me one of the solution with example code.

appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Why do you need to write the file at all? I have created attachments in `MailMessage` directly from `MemoryStream`.

Comment: I have tried that and can view the file in browser using memorystream. BUT somehow using the meorystream, i can not attach the file to MailMessage.. i would like to use that approach only. BUT its not working out so thats why i choose this approach.. Please help

Comment: please [see my earlier post using the Memorystream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774211/having-issue-with-attaching-the-pdf-file-from-memory-stream-using-itextsharp)

Comment: Are you certain you need to reset the `MemoryStream` before adding to the attachment? Did you debug through to see that it is indeed not empty?

Comment: yes, to get file as attachment we need to set the memorystream position to 0.. thats what google search returned to me.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it's better to use the MemoryStream as-is without writing temporary files to the disk. Sometimes implementations of 3rd party components just won't allow this and in such cases after writing the binary contents of the PDF file, be sure to call close (and/or possibly dispose, always check MSDN or 3rd party API docs what the .Close() actually does) to all streams that are no longer needed. In your case close *ms* and *reader* after completing the http request.

In most cases, consider implementing the using pattern. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736.aspx for more details. However remember that there are caveats to this approach too, for example in WCF clients which can cause exceptions within (and thus not actually disposing all contents inside the using clause).

Also, keep in mind any concurrency issues. Keep the temporary file name random enough and consider situations where the file already exists on the local disk (i.e. fail the operation and do not send out binary to the request which the requester is not supposed to see etc).

Comment: if you can see my earlier post on this using [Memorystream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774211/having-issue-with-attaching-the-pdf-file-from-memory-stream-using-itextsharp), i cant seems to attach the file somehow.  please let me know what i am doing wrong in that..

Comment: Passing the MemoryStream around (and closing the associated readers/writers before returning such handles) is not a good idea. Create the PDF binary data in one method and then return that data as-is, with all unnecessary streams closed immediately after they are not needed. Simplified, but still: using the stream is ideal only if the stream needs to be handled/edited/transformed/etc in any way between the methods. Otherwise you just need to keep track on closing (and rewinding i.e. repositioning) all open streams by places which call the methods creating them in the first place.

Comment: so u suggesting that passing the stream might be closing the stream so  thats whay i am not able to attach the file.

Comment: Yes. You can verify this with debugging: just check if the stream is null immediately before you try to return it. If so, then try what happens if you don't close the stream. If it works, then.. well.. you've got working code, expect for the fact that now you need to handle the closing of the stream anyways (somewhere else). If this indeed is the case, I do suggest rewriting the code not to pass the stream.

Comment: i added a condition to check if ms != null .. and its not null but somehow its not rendering in the browser.

Comment: OK.. i can view the PDF in browser using memorystream. Does that mean i can use the same meorystream as an attachment to email?

Comment: It should work, provided that the stream is not closed in between the reads. Also remember to rewind the stream when reading it again.